# How to make a volatile state in react-router history?

Tags: react-router, react-router-v4, react-router-dom

I am currently working on showing success/fail message on the redirected page.

The workflow will look like this,

1. User type something in pageA and submit. then do history.push to next page.

   ```
       history.push(/pageB/path, {message: 'Success!'});
   ```
2. and in pageB, it will show success message on the top.

However, this success message will be there forever, then this will confuse user if they follow the previous steps and go to pageA again. And then go back to pageB(could be back button on browser or cancel button on the form) without submit. This message will still be shown on top of the page.

My goal is to only show message after user submit the form. So my question is is there a way to make the history state volatile so the message won't show up when user just went back to pageB.

Any suggestion is welcome. Thanks!

Edit: My currently solution is checking history's action(pop or push) and only show message when action is push. But looking for any better solution.

Edit: To more clarify my problem. Here is user action and browser history.

1. Action: user in pageA and submit form.

   History:

   0: pageA
2. Action: user has been redirected to pageB(with success message)

   History:

   0: pageA

   1: pageB with history.location.state.message = ...
3. Action: user go to pageA again without submit a form

   History:

   0: pageA

   1: pageB with history.location.state.message = ...

   2: pageA
4. Action: user go back to pageB by back button of browser

   History:

   0: pageA

   1: pageB with history.location.state.message = ...

In the step 4, it goes back to old history 1 which has message set in state so it will still present(but should not, because user didn't submit a form).

Edit: I am thinking if it is possible to directly modify history to remove the state from the page?

Comment: Do you mean that whilst the user is on pageB for certain amount of time you want to remove the mesage ```successs``` ? Or your problem is that whenever user end in pageB there will always be success message even if they dont go there after form submit?

Comment: @MatthewBarbara Close to your second one. The desire behavior is 1. user submit form in pageA and redirect to pageB 2. show success/fail message on top of pageB. 3. User go to pageA again but don't submit form and return to pageB by back button. 4. PageB should not show any message since user didn't do anything. However, in step 4, the message will still be there because message is recorded by history.

Answer (score 0):

with the following code you can pass the prop after a form is submitted

```
history.push({pathname:'/pageB', message: 'successs'})
```

and then in `pageB`

```
this.setState({ isMessageTextTimeExpired: false }) // in constructor

componentDidMount() {
    if (this.state.isMessageTextTimeExpired) {
        setTimeout( () => {
            this.setState({ isMessageTextTimeExpired: true });
        }, 5000) // your desire time to hide message
     }
}

componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    const previousPath = this.props.location.pathname;
    if (previousPath === 'pathA') {
      this.setState({ isMessageTextTimeExpired: true })
    }
  }


render() {
    const { redirectMessage } = this.props.history.location;
    const { isMessageTextTimeExpired } = this.state;
    return (
          redirectMessage && isMessageTextTimeExpired ? redirectMessage : null // print redirectMessage if it exist
   )
}
```

With the above, whenever you reach `pathB` without passing it `message` it would simply not show anything. If `message` exist it will be rendered but removed after 5 seconds. Also, if your previous path was `pathA` it would not show the `message`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, it is not what exactly I am looking for. Please see my question above. I have update my question. Actually, we have similar code right now. With this code, after you show the message and go to another page then hit back button of browser. Message will still be there. I am looking for a way to remove this message because it should not be there. Because I think it will confuse user while they actually done nothing and page tell them you just made a change.

Comment: is your problem only occurring when the user clicks the browsers back button?

Comment: Updated my answer. When you go to /pathB/  ```componentWillReceiveProps``` will check the previous props and if the history.location.pathname is from pathA, it would change the state of ```isMessageTextTimeExpired``` to false. This should solve your problem.

Comment: I think I would like to make it more general. After user is in pageB with message, it doesn't matter what user do next(it can go to pageC and come back or just Back and Next from the browser or even just refresh the page). The message should be shown whenever user come back to the pageB(the old pageB in history).  So your answer might not work if user just refresh and go back or something else.